# How to display values from a column of a table which are non existant and display zero beside it in SQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

I have a table:

```
Id|Name  |orders|units    
1 |Tom   |6     |4    
2 |Lucy  |4     |8    
3 |Frank |3     |7  
4 |Jane  |2     |5    
5 |Robert|1     |NULL
```

I want the output as:

```
Id|units  
1 |4  
4 |5  
5 |0  
8 |0  
9 |0
```

Can you help me with the query?

Comment: Are you using mysql or Oracle? You flagged both in your question.

Comment: Anything will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this meets your requirements because I have no idea where & why your result set misses IDs 2 and 3. Anyway, here you are: full outer join with a *fabricated* set of IDs from 1 to 9.

```
SQL> with test (id, units) as
  2    (select 1, 4 from dual union
  3     select 2, 8 from dual union
  4     select 3, 7 from dual union
  5     select 4, 5 from dual union
  6     select 5, null from dual
  7    )
  8  select x.column_value id, nvl(t.units, 0) units
  9  from test t full outer join
 10       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                           connect by level < 10
 12                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist)) x
 13       on x.column_value = t.id;

        ID      UNITS
---------- ----------
         1          4
         2          8
         3          7
         4          5
         5          0
         6          0
         7          0
         8          0
         9          0

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `IFNULL` to the query. Like `IFNULL(Units, 0)`

Comment: What about 8, 9 in the ID of the output which is non-existent in the main table.

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen this part. Do you always want to add only two rows or is this just an example? Generally, you could create another table with all the IDs you want to show and then (left/right) join both tables.